# JwPlayer: dynamic change video

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jwplayer

I have jwPlayer on my page and the following markup:

```
div class="block_video">
    <div class="slider_video" id="slider_video">
        <div class="navigation_container">
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul class="thumbs">
                    <% foreach (var publicationVideo in Model.PublicationVideos)
                       {%>
                    <li><a id='<%=publicationVideo.PathToVideo %>' data-isurl="<%=publicationVideo.IsUrl %>" href="/assets/images/i/2.jpg" class="thumb" title="<%=Model.Name %>">
                        <img  src="/assets/images/video-content.png" width="49px" height="41px" />
                    </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div id="video_player">
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption_video">
                                <%=Model.Name %></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <% } %>
                </ul>
                <!-- .thumbs-->
            </div>
            <!-- .navigation-->
        </div>
        <!-- .navigation_container-->
        <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="render">
            </div>
            <div class="caption-container">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .slideshow-->
    </div>
    <!-- .slider_video-->
</div>
<!-- .block_video-->
```

It's looks as follows:
[image]

When page is load all works fine(first video was load). But when I click on another video(on image) then player is dissapper. If I click again then player is apper. And another problem: When I click on all images twice, then when I click for example on the first, it plays the previous loaded file, click once again plays the correct file.

This is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isUrlOnReady = $(".block_video a").attr("data-isurl");
        var providerOnReady;
        if (isUrlOnReady === "True")
            providerOnReady = "youtube";
        else
            providerOnReady = "http";

        loadPlayer('<%=Url.Action("GetVideo", "Video", new {videoName = Model.PublicationVideos[0].PathToVideo}) %>', providerOnReady);           


        $(".block_video a").click(function () {
            var isUrl = $(this).attr("data-isurl");
            var fileName = $(this).attr("id");
            var provider;
            var path;

            if (isUrl === "True") {
                provider = "youtube";
                path = fileName;
            }
            else {
                provider = "http";
                path = '<%=Url.Action("GetVideo", "Video", new {videoName = -1}) %>';
                path = path.replace("-1", fileName);
            }


            loadPlayer(path, provider);

        });
    });

// load player
function loadPlayer(fileName, provider) {
    jwplayer("video_player").setup({
        flashplayer: '<%=Url.Content("~/assets/js/jwplayer/player.swf")%>',
        file: fileName,
        height: 173,
        width: 210,
        provider: provider,
        controlbar: 'bottom'
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Why are you trying to reinitialize the player every time? Use its API and submit to player URL  of the media file. Simple example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   jwplayer('player').setup({
        flashplayer: 'player.swf',
        height: 173,
        autostart: true,
        width: 210,
        controlbar: 'bottom'
    });
   $('.media').click(function(){
       jwplayer().load($(this).text());
   })      
 });
</script>
<div id='player'></div><br />
<div class='media'>video.mp4</div>
<div class='media'>video2.mp4</div>
```

Without `autostart: true` you can load media and play it as

```
jwplayer().load($(this).text()).play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the previous answers ! That help me ! (but the answer is not up to date).

Actually, with all last versions of jwPlayer, we can't load directly a new video from this URL. We must to add this video to playlist (with the `load()` method) with a valid JSON like that :

`jwplayer().load("https://mywebsite.com/myplaylist.json");`

or with an array like that :

```
jwplayer('myElement').load([{
  file: "/videos/myVideo.mp4",
  image: "/images/myImage.png",
  title: "My Favorite Video!",
  description: "This has lots of kittens in it!"
}]);
```

You can see all the API reference [here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#section-jwplayer-load-playlist)